# How to make jquery detect html elements inside a certain element?

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

I am trying to detect the current position of cursor when button is clicked. However my script is only able to detect the position of the cursor according to the text, not counting the html elements. How do I make this function to detect and count the html elements too ? Example below.

html

```
<div>This is a text</div>        <!-- If cursor is at after the word 'is', 
                                 position should be 7 -->
<div><ul><li>This is text with ul and li elements</li></ul></div>    
                                 <!-- If cursor is at after the word 'is',
                                 position should be 15 (counting the ul and li elements) -->
<button class='button'>Button</button>
```

js

```
$(document).ready(function() {
    $('.button').click(function() {
        var position = window.getSelection().getRangeAt(0).startOffset;
        alert(position);
    });
});
```

Jsfiddle

http://jsfiddle.net/mjgcyy3x/

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Maybe something like [this](http://jsfiddle.net/Arg0n/g87sysyp/1/):

HTML:

```
<div class="container">This is a text</div>
<div class="container"><ul><li>There is ul and li elements here</li></ul></div>
<button class='button'>Button</button>
```

JavaScript:

```
$(document).ready(function() {
    $('.button').click(function() {
        var text = window.getSelection().anchorNode
        if(text) {
            var container = $(text).closest(".container");
            var htmlLength = container.html().indexOf(text.textContent);
            var position = window.getSelection().getRangeAt(0).startOffset;
            alert(htmlLength + position);
        }
    });
});
```

Comment: You are amazing. Thank you very much. Been wrecking my brain for a day just for this. Thank you

Answer (score 0):

This should work:

```
$(document).ready(function() {
    $('.button').click(function() {
        var position = window.getSelection().getRangeAt(0).startOffset;

        var selection = window.getSelection();
        if (selection.rangeCount > 0) {
            var container = $(selection.getRangeAt(0).startContainer.parentNode).closest('div');
            var text = container.text();
            var htmlText = container.html();
            position += htmlText.indexOf(text);
        }

        alert(position);
    });
});
```

[jsFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/mjgcyy3x/1/)